# how to display a list of linkedhashmap type in tabular format in java

Tags: java, list, jsp

I have a list which holds data of LinkedHashMap type as:-

```
       LinkedHashMap<Date,Double> map21 = new LinkedHashMap<Date,Double>();

      List<LinkedHashMap<Date,Double>>l=new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<Date,Double>>();   
          {
            rs.absolute(43);
            map20.put(rs.getDate(1),rs.getDouble(2));
            l.add(map20);
            rs.absolute(45);
            map21.put(rs.getDate(1),rs.getDouble(2));
            l.add(map21);
            l.addAll(l);
          }
         return l
```

I display it in jsp as:

```
<table width = "300px" border = "1" cellspacing="2">
<tr> 
<th>logtime</th>
<th>beam_current</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${ref.reference()}">
<tr> 
<c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">
<td>
${column}
</td> 
</c:forEach>
 </tr>  
 </c:forEach>
 </table>
```

Now the output displayed after executing JSP page is a table with two columns but the values of both the columns are filled or displayed in first column namely logtime.How to show logtime value in first column and second column value in beam_current column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way 
iterate the `Map` is to get its `key` and `value`. Therefore iterate it as ,

```
<table width = "300px" border = "1" cellspacing="2">
   <tr>
      <th>logtime</th>
      <th>beam_current</th>
   </tr>
   <c:forEach var="row" items="${ref.reference()}">
      <tr>
         <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">
            <td>
               ${column.key}
            </td>
            <td>
               ${column.value}
            </td>
         </c:forEach>
      </tr>
   </c:forEach>
</table>
```

will display the desired result in the tabular form